# Data Table with Inline Editing -- On click of Edit button Page got refreshed LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

On click of Data Table with Inline Edit, whole page got refreshed, Not able to find the issue. Can anyone please help me on this? ( LWC using in Visual-force Page)

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import createParentGuardian from "@salesforce/apex/GetParentGuardianController.createParentGuardian";
import getParentdetails from "@salesforce/apex/GetParentGuardianController.getParentdetails";
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";

import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Id';

const columns = [
{ label: "First Name", fieldName: "FirstName", editable: true },
{ label: "Last Name", fieldName: "LastName" },
{ label: "Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "phone" },
{ label: "Email", fieldName: "Email", type: "email" },
{ label: "Student Relation", fieldName: "Student_Relation__c" }
];



@track error;
 @track data;

 @wire(getParentdetails, { enrollmentName: "a082w000000YUH5AAO" })
 getContacts(response) {
console.log('one');
    this.wiredDataRefresh = response;
const data = response.data;
const error = response.error;
if (data) {
  this.data = data;
  return refreshApex(this.wiredDataRefresh);
} else if (error) {
  this.error = error;
}
}



handleSave(event) {
const fields = {};
    fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].Id;
    fields[FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].FirstName;
    fields[LASTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].LastName;
    const recordInput = {fields};

    updateRecord(recordInput)
    .then(() => {
      this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
              title: 'Success',
              message: 'Contact updated',
              variant: 'success'
          })
      );
      // Clear all draft values
      this.draftValues = [];

      // Display fresh data in the datatable
      return refreshApex(this.wiredDataRefresh);
  })

  }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="slds-p-top_x-large">
                            <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns}
                                draft-values={draftValues} hide-checkbox-column="true" onsave={handleSave}
                                resize-column-disabled="true">
                            </lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `getParentdetails` wire I think you are triggering the refreshApex unnecessarily:

```
if (data) {
  this.data = data;
  return refreshApex(this.wiredDataRefresh);  // Remove this
}
```

I think this might be causing the problem in your component.

Comment: Removed that code, still i have the same issue :(

Comment: You're also missing the property for wiredDataRefresh. Add `wiredDataRefresh;` under `@track data;`.